# how can I exit from a php script and continue right after the script?

Tags: php

Hey guys, I have this piece of code, and when I add return after echo(if there is an error and I need to continue right after the script) I can't see the footer, do you know what the problem is?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>Login | JM Today </title>
    <link href="Mainstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
    <?php include("navbar.php"); ?>
    <?php include("cleanquery.php") ?>  

    <div id="wrap">


       <?php
       ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

        $conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "***", "***") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('jmtdy', $conn) or die(mysql_error());

        if(isset($_POST['sublogin'])){

        if(( strlen($_POST['user']) >0) && (strlen($_POST['pass']) >0)) {

            checklogin($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']);

        }
        elseif((isset($_POST['user']) && empty($_POST['user'])) || (isset($_POST['pass']) && empty($_POST['pass']))){

            echo '<p class="statusmsg">You didn\'t fill in the required fields.</p><br/><input type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
            return;
        }
        }
        else{

            echo '<p class="statusmsg">You came here by mistake, didn\'t you?</p><br/><input type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
            return;

        }   

      function checklogin($username, $password){

        $username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password=mysql_real_escape_string($password);

            $result=mysql_query("select * from users where username = '$username'");
            if($result != false){

                $dbArray=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $dbArray['password']=mysql_real_escape_string($dbArray['password']);
                $dbArray['username']=mysql_real_escape_string($dbArray['username']);

                if(($dbArray['password'] != $password ) || ($dbArray['username'] != $username)){
                    echo '<p class="statusmsg">The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.</p><br/><input type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
                    return;
                }
                $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                $_SESSION['password']=$password;

                if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                    setcookie("jmuser",$_SESSION['username'],time()+60*60*24*356);  
                    setcookie("jmpass",$_SESSION['username'],time()+60*60*24*356);
                }
            }

            else{
                echo'<p class="statusmsg">  The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.</p><br/>input type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
                return;
            }
        }           


      ?>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
<?php include("footer.php") ?>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Oh, and if the username and password is incorrect I could see the footer.

Comment: What is the question exactly? If you "return" or "exit," the script will not finish executing passed that point. I would not use "return" outside of functions, but where are you hitting your error? It looks to me like everything works properly. If you ever encounter an error, you're sending a return after the error message, so it stops the script at that point.

Comment: I know that, but why doesn't the footer appear after the first two errors, but appears after "the username or password is incorrect"?

Comment: Since your "username and password is incorrect" is located within a function, the function ends, but the script finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a return statement and you are not inside a function, the script will exit, thus the parser never reaches the statement that imports the footer. Keep in mind your script is the entire document, not just the parts enclosed in tags. If the parser stops somewhere, the entire rest of the document is left out.

Comment: Is there a way I could exit just the parts enclosed in tags? Or some other way to be able to see the error?

Comment: From what I can tell, the only way to do that would be with some sort of if statement. But in my opinion, you do not really need to skip the rest of the script, because after the error message is echoed, the only thing left is a function definition, which isn't doing anything. You can safely just take out the return statements and everything should work OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exit out of a script and continue running the same script.

But some advice about your return statements:

1) If your function doesn't return anything, then don't put a return statement in there.

2) Use only one return statement per function, it will make your code more clear.

Comment: Return statements allow a void (if you want to declare a type; in PHP any function really) function to terminate early, so it's not always important to return a value. return; or return null; is a valid result for a function since PHP does not have strict types like C++

Comment: I don't think you understand, RageD, there is no reason to add a return statement if the function returns no value regardless if return permits a void or not. It's wasted meaningless typing and clutters up the code.

Comment: And adding useless returns can create perfectly avoidable problems like the one above.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove "return" (leave it only in functions) nothing will change in this case, but you'll see you footer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the RETURN statements on lines 33 and 39

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert your php part as a **php include**. The return; statement will only stop the execution of the included php and it will continue the rest after the included.

`<?php include("footer.php") ?>`  will output the footer.